# C++11 Lambda functions implicit conversion to bool vs. std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, overloading

Consider this simple example code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void f(bool _switch) {
    std::cout << "Nothing really" << std::endl;
}

void f(std::function<double (int)> _f) {
    std::cout << "Nothing really, too" << std::endl;
}

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    f([](int _idx){ return 7.9;});
    return 0;
}
```

It fails to compile:

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:15:33: error: call of overloaded ‘f(main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>)’ is ambiguous
main.cpp:15:33: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:6:6: note: void f(bool)
main.cpp:10:6: note: void f(std::function<double(int)>)
```

However if I replace the second function with a reference argument it compiles fine. And again if it is replaced by a const reference it fails.

So I have some questions concerning this example:

- Why is a lambda function implicitly convertible to `bool` in the first place?
- Why does taking a std::function reference solve the ambiguity?
- And most important to me, how can I avoid this problem? I need the second function to take either a (copy of a) std::function or a const reference to it.

Comment: Overloading a function taking a `std::function` is currently not a good idea. There's a greedy constructor template of `std::function` in C++11 that is not required to (SFINAE-)reject "invalid" types. That is, the second overload can match any type. It is then ranked as a User-Defined Conversion, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
namespace details{
  template<class Sig,class=void>
  struct invoke {};
  template<class F, class...Args>
  struct invoke<F(Args...),decltype(void(
    std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...)
  ))>{
    using type=decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...));
  };
}
template<class Sig>struct invoke:details::invoke<Sig>{};

template<typename Sig, typename T, typename=void>
struct invoke_test:std::false_type {};
template<typename R, typename...Args, typename T>
struct invoke_test<R(Args...), T,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible<
      typename invoke<T(Args...)>::type,
      R
    >::value
  >::type
>:std::true_type {};
template<typename...Args,typename T>
struct invoke_test<void(Args...),T,
  decltype( void( typename invoke<T(Args...)>::type ) )
>:std::true_type{};
template<typename Sig, typename T>
constexpr bool invokable() {
  return invoke_test<Sig,T>::value;
}
```

this gives us a pseudo-concept `invokable`.

We can then use it like:

```
template<typename F>
typename std::enable_if<invokable<double(int),F>()>::type
f(F&&){
  std::cout << "can be invoked\n";
}
void f(bool) {
  std::cout << "is bool\n";
}
```

and bob is your uncle.

The real problem is that `std::function<double(int)>` 's constructor does not do a similar test, and instead claims (falsely) that it can be constructed from anything at all.  This is a flaw in the standard, one I suspect will be fixed once concepts are standardized.

Answer (score 9):

A lambda function with no capture can be converted to a regular function pointer, which then has a standard conversion to a bool.

If you take the `std::function` by non-const reference, then that eliminates it as a candidate, since converting the lambda to a `std::function` requires a temporary, and a temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference.  That just leaves `f(bool)` as a candidate, so there is no ambiguity.

There are many ways you could avoid the ambiguity.  For example, you could create a `std::function` variable first:

```
std::function<double(int)> g = [](int _idx){ return 7.9;};
f(g);
```

or you could cast the lambda:

```
f(std::function<double(int)>([](int _idx){return 7.9;}));
```

You could have a helper function:

```
template<typename T>
std::function<T> make_function(T *f) { return {f}; } 

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    f(make_function([](int _idx){ return 7.9;}));
    return 0;
}
```

or you could grab the particular function you are interested in:

```
int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    void (*f_func)(std::function<double(int)>) = f;
    f_func([](int _idx){ return 7.9;});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may be an awful solution (or it may not) but using `f([&](int _idx){ return 7.9;});` should also work, right?

Comment: No, since no reference is being used in the lambda function, compiler will still convert it to a function pointer. Just use, for instance 'argc', then it will not be converted to a function pointer.

Comment: @bmm Never thought about that, thanks. Trying it on coliru, [g++ thinks it's ambiguous](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3623b742f907d35f), but [clang++ accepts it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c9defb40ecc9c34).

Comment: @bmm The Standard makes the existence of this conversion operator dependent on whether or not the lambda has a *lambda-capture*, not on whether or not it actually captures anything. Hence, cv_and_he's solution *should* work (although I'd say it's a hack).

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of the implicit conversion by creating a helper class

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Boolean { 
    bool state; 
    Boolean(bool b):state(b){} 
    operator bool(){ return state; } 
};
void f(Boolean _switch) {
    std::cout << "Nothing really " << _switch << std::endl;
}

void f(std::function<double (int)> _f) {
    std::cout << "Nothing really, too" << std::endl;
}

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    f([](int _idx){ return 7.9;});
    f(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Should you ever want to call `f` with eg. a pointer and expect it to call the first overload you will have to cast it to either `bool` or add a corresponding constructor / cast to the helper class though.

Comment: This sadly fails if you also have an integer overload of the same function, e.g. void f(int _i); When you call it with f(true), the integer overload will be selected instead with the value coerced to 1. :(

Answer (score 2):

One more option to [Vaughn Cato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23162819/2644390):

```
template<typename F>
void f(F _f) {
    std::cout << "Nothing really, too: " << _f(3) << std::endl;
}
```

Now the second overload is a template, so it is chosen for a lambda (or anything), and the first is chosen for `bool`. So calling `f` is no more complex than needed.

But, one problem with that is if you want to add more overloads, and another is that the first overload will only be called if there is an exact match to `bool`.

Comment: I feel it's generally a bad idea to overload non-template functions and template functions, especially when the template would have nominally matched the non-template.  If you intend to call the non-template but your type doesn't match ***exactly***, you'll end up calling the template.  For example, `f(feof(some_FILE))` will call the template, even though `feof()` only returns an `int` (rather than a `bool`) by historical accident.

Comment: @Adam Depends on intended use. If you want conversions, of course you don't do that. But if you know what you're doing, it can be a very good idea. I've added the limitation, thanks.

Comment: I've never found it to be a very good idea.  IMAO it's far too brittle.  Are you saying that in this context, someone calling `f(feof(some_FILE))` would prefer the `int` be treated as a function?  If you have some `g(int)` overloaded with a `g<T>(T)`, you'll get the template for an `unsigned`, a `char`, (sometimes) an `int16_t`, or pretty much anything that would normally be benignly converted to `int`.  `const` conversions and derived-to-base conversions are also routinely used by programmers use without thinking about or realizing, which will also break with an overload set like this.

Comment: @Adam I said "If you want conversions, of course you don't do that." This includes your `f(feof(some_FILE))` example. Yes, it's a very bad idea in that case.

Comment: Maybe you should make it less greedy by using some SFINAE magic. `std::function` should do that too, although it's not required to do so.