# Overload resolution ambiguous

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
void f(bool);
void f(std::function<bool()>);

int main()
{
    f([](){ return true;});
}
```

This is an ambiguous call in clang/gcc but works in vs. Link: https://godbolt.org/z/xcuoIN
Why is this happening. Bool and function returning bool are different types.

Comment: I assume your question is "which compiler is correct?", yes?

Comment: @BoBTFish Updated

Comment: Related: [C++11 Lambda functions implicit conversion to bool vs. std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23162654/580083)

Comment: clang and gcc are correct.   The call in `main()` requires a conversion to call either version of `f()`.   Both conversions are possible, and the compiler has no reason to prefer one over the other, hence the ambiguity.

Comment: @DanielLangr seems like a duplicate to me

Comment: @M.M Kind of, but not exactly. OP also asks why the code works in MSVC, which is not mentioned in the duplicate.